# Website Desktop mode in mobile landscape

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to force my website to **desktop mode** in **mobile landscape view**. by using the meta tag width="1024" website is loading in desktop mode in mobile portrait mode but for landscape, it is not working.